# MacBook Pro M1 cocoapods install

Tags: macos, cocoapods

Getting below error while installing the cocoapods on new MacBook Pro with M1 through terminal:

```
sudo gem install cocoapods                         
Password:
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing cocoapods:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.5/ext/ffi_c
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/bin/ruby -I /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0 -r ./siteconf20230310-5338-1i32qm0.rb extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h

You might have to install separate package for the ruby development
environment, ruby-dev or ruby-devel for example.

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.5 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/extensions/universal-darwin-22/2.6.0/ffi-1.15.5/gem_make.out
```

Can anyone suggest what to do for cocoapods install on the MacBook Pro?

I run the following commands:

1. sudo gem install cocoapods (getting above error)
2. /usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL    https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"

Comment: There are compatibility issues with some versions of Ruby and the M1 macs... https://antran.app/2021/m1_mac_part2/ Have a look here. It might help.

Comment: Consider that more and more third-party libraries are available via Swift Package Manager which is much more convenient (and less tedious) than CocoaPods.

Answer (score 0):

Run:

> arch -x86_64 pod install

It works for me.